# What takes less space: debootstrap or Ubuntu Core?

Tags: disk-usage, debootstrap, ubuntu-core

I have a very small disk in my netbook.

So I decided to offload all development files into chroot on an external drive.

What will take less space initially, debootstrap installation or Ubuntu Core image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of vivid, the Ubuntu Core image is a debootstrap minbase image and some very light postprocessing.

Source: I've compared both.

Answer (score 3):

## 12.04

#### Short:

Ubuntu Core

#### Detailed:

On current 12.04.3 installation (`df`/`du` output):

```
debootstrap  210352
Core         110424
```

Core image doesn't have these packages:

> apt-utils bzip2 console-setup cron debconf-i18n dmsetup eject file
> iputils-ping isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kbd
> keyboard-configuration less libapt-inst1.4 libdevmapper1.02.1
> libexpat1 libfribidi0 liblocale-gettext-perl liblockfile-bin
> liblockfile1 libmagic1 libnewt0.52 libpopt0 libsqlite3-0
> libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl
> lockfile-progs logrotate lsb-release mime-support net-tools netbase
> netcat-openbsd ntpdate python python2.7 resolvconf rsyslog sudo
> ubuntu-minimal ucf ureadahead vim-common vim-tiny whiptail xkb-data

Comment: Keep in mind that the compressed [rootfs of "Ubuntu Core"](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/) has almost doubled in size (amd64) [**63M**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/) **since release 14.04**, before 14.04 core rootfs was [**38M**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.10/release/). Uncompressed Ubuntu Core 14.04 rootfs is even much larger. Note: rootfs excludes the kernel.